# Finding which of an array of IDs has no record with a single query

Tags: mysql, join, pdo

I'm generating prepared statements with PHP PDO to pull in information from two tables based on an array of IDs.

Then I realized that if an ID passed had no record I wouldn't know.

I'm locating records with

```
SELECT 
    r.`DEANumber`, 
    TRIM(r.`ActivityCode`) AS ActivityCode, 
    TRIM(r.`ActivitySubCode`) as ActivitySubCode, 
    // other fields...
    a.Activity
FROM 
    `registrants` r,
    `activities` a
WHERE r.`DEAnumber` IN ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
    AND a.Code = ActivityCode
    AND a.Subcode = ActivitySubCode
```

But I am having trouble figuring out the negative join that says which of the IDs has no record.

If two tables were involved I think I could do it like this

```
SELECT
r.DEAnumber
FROM registrant r
LEFT JOIN registrant2 r2 ON r.DEAnumber = r2.DEAnumber
WHERE r2.DEAnumber IS NULL
```

But I'm stumped as to how to use the array of IDs here.  Obviously I could iterate over the array and track which queries had not result but it seems like such a manual and wasteful way to go...

Comment: I've not put this as an answer because I can't fully verify it but try : JOIN (SELECT 1,2,3) AS r2 and your IS NULL check - effectively a derived table.

Comment: @Ukuser32 - I'm unclear.  Do you you mean like this?  SELECT
r.DEAnumber
FROM registrants r
JOIN (SELECT DEANumber FROM registrants WHERE DEAnumber IN ('A90777889','A91109796','A91565778','A91955650','A92055879','george')) AS r2
WHERE r2 IS NULL
AND r.DEAnumber IN ('A90777889','A91109796','A91565778','A91955650','A92055879','george')

Comment: Do you want all `registrants` that have no associated `activities` rows, or all id's that have no corresponding `registrants` row at all? Or something else? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously I could iterate over the array and track which queries had not result but it seems like such a manual and wasteful way to go.

What could be a *real* waste is spending time solving this non-existent "problem".

Yes, you could iterate. Either manually, or using a syntax sugar like `array_diff()` in PHP.

I suggest that instead of making your query more complex (means heavier to support) for little gain, you just move on.

As old man Knuth once said 'premature optimization is the root of all evil'.

The only thing I could think of a help from PDO is a [fetch mode that will put IDs as keys for the returned array](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#unique), and thus you'll be able to make it without [explicitly written] loop, like

```
$stmt->execute($ids);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
$notFound = array_diff($ids, array_keys($data));
```

Yet a manual loop would have taken only two extra lines, which is, honestly, not that a big deal to talk about.

Comment: I'd also add that generally you'll be iterating the data anyway, particularly with related models being pulled in.. with data keyed by id, just iterate the original array of ids and look for `isset(data[$id])`

Comment: Thank you.  Will award bounty in 6 hours when allowed.  was hoping for something like this broken query where my result says 'fred' was not found. select r.DEAnumber from registrants r left join registrants r2 on r.DEAnumber = r2.DEAnumber where r.DEAnumber IN ( 'A90777889','A92973750','fred','A93062445' ) and r2.DEAnumber is null but I see wisdom of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track - a left join that filters *out* matches will give you the missing joins. You just need to move all conditions on the left-joined table up into the join.

If you leave the conditions on the joined table in the `where` clause you effectively cause an inner join, because the `where` clause is executed on the rows *after* the join is made, which is too late if there was no join in the first place.

Change the query to use proper join syntax, specifying a *left* join, with the conditions on `activity` moved to the join'n `on` clause:

```
SELECT 
    r.DEANumber, 
    TRIM(r.ActivityCode) AS ActivityCode, 
    TRIM(r.ActivitySubCode) as ActivitySubCode, 
    // other fields...
    a.Activity
FROM registrants r
LEFT JOIN activities a ON a.Code = ActivityCode
    AND a.Subcode = ActivitySubCode
WHERE r.DEAnumber IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

In your app code, if `Activity` is `null` then you know there was no activity for that id.

This won't affect performance much, other than to return (potentially) more rows.

---

To just select all registrants without activities:

```
select r.DEAnumber
from registrants r
left join activities a on a.Code = ActivityCode
    and a.Subcode = ActivitySubCode
where r.`DEAnumber` IN ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
and a.Code is null
```

Comment: I think that his problem is not in finding the corresponding records in the jonied table, but just in finding whether there was any IDs absent in the main table. For which he indeed needs a derived table with all IDs to be joined, if SQL solution to be used.

Comment: So what I was hoping for was something like this broken query where my result says 'fred' was not found.  select r.DEAnumber from registrants r left join registrants r2 on r.DEAnumber = r2.DEAnumber where r.`DEAnumber` IN ( 'A90777889','A92973750','fred','A93062445' ) and r2.DEAnumber is null

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - If Bohemian's second query does not do that, please provide both sample data and expected output.

Comment: @RickJames Bohemian's second answer shows records which have a record in registrant but none in activities.  I need to know which records from the array in the query itself IN() have no record in registrants.

Comment: Why is `activities` mentioned; it seems irrelevant.